# Fuse esb - using quartz

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

i want to build simple copy from folder to folder application using camel:

```
  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
    <to uri="file:src/data/new"/>
  </route>
  </camelContext>
```

I wanted to add quartz to copy file every 5 seconds.

I found something like this:

```
<bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent">
    <property name="startDelayedSeconds" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

but i don't know how to use it to in my example.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use quartz. Just change your from:
file:src/data?noop=true&consumer.delay=5000

Comment: Its easier to just say delay=5s for 5 seconds, eg <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true&delay=5s"/>

Comment: Cool think. Did not know this. Your proposed format is better as it avoids the implicit knowledge that the number is milliseconds.